# DllNotFoundException -- VisStudio 2008, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

This just started happening with an application that has been working:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
A first chance exception of type '.ModuleLoadException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

How do I figure out which dll is missing?
TIA for any hints...

Comment: I guess you could try re-installing .NET 3.5 SP1...

Comment: As Reed suggested, use the fusion log. Here's a good article on using it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Cool.  D/l a fresh dotnetfx35setup.exe, run it, get a dialog that says "Setup error" with no other information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to check for missing assembly dependencies, or [Depends.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738370(WS.10).aspx) for native dependencies.